# Informações logo abaixo do título da pergunta estão em inglês

Tags: bug, tradução

Hoje reparei que, logo abaixo do título da pergunta, estão aparecendo algumas informações sobre a mesma (que antes ficavam em outras partes, como a quantidade de visualizações, que antes ficava do lado).

Porém, estas informações estão em inglês. Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está assim tanto no site principal quanto no meta. Outro exemplo:

[image: info]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que as traduções sejam:

- `Asked`, deveria ser "Criada", "Publicada" ou "Perguntada"?

  - https://pt.traducir.win/string/11480
- `Active` = Ativa

  - https://pt.traducir.win/string/11475
- `Viewed` = Visualizada

  - https://pt.traducir.win/string/11476
- `$viewsPretty$ times` = $viewsPretty$ vez(es)

  - https://pt.traducir.win/string/11477
  - https://pt.traducir.win/string/11478

---

As traduções foram aprovadas (porém, "Viewed" ficou como "Vista", em vez de "Visualizada"). Ex:

- site principal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- meta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na página principal, as perguntas aparecem como  "Perguntada", então acho que deveria manter assim aqui (se bem que acho meio estranho, talvez fosse o caso de mudar **ambas** para "Publicada"?)

Comment: Vc reparou que agora "Viewed" aparece como "Vista", mas o restante ainda está em inglês? O que aconteceu? :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Parece que alguém aprovou a tradução para "vista", mas não analisou as outras.