# Descrição de medalhas Lifejacket e Lifeboat não traduzidas

Tags: bug, tradução

Por favor verificar, as descrições das medalhas "Lifejacket" e "Lifeboat" não estão traduzidas conforme a imagem.

Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual seria melhor tradução ?

Answer (score 1):

Como o nome sugere, essas medalhas são dadas para pessoas que responderam a pergunta de alguém, e graças a essa resposta, a pergunta ficou positiva novamente. Então suponho que a tradução deve ser essa:

- Colete salva-vidas: Resposta com pontuação de 5 ou superior, para uma pergunta com pontuação de -2 ou inferior, que depois passou a ter pontuação de 2 ou superior.
- Bote salva-vidas: Resposta com pontuação de 20 ou superior, para uma pergunta com pontuação de -3 ou inferior, que depois passou a ter pontuação de 3 ou superior.

Comment: Apenas para manter a consistência com as demais descrições da [página de medalhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), lá é usado "perguntas" em vez de "questões". E a pontuação é descrita como "pontuação de X ou superior", além disso a descrição não fala sobre a quantidade de respostas, e sim sobre a pontuação da mesma, então seria algo como *"Resposta com pontuação de 5 ou superior, para uma pergunta com pontuação de -2 ou inferior, que depois passou a ter pontuação de 2 ou superior"*

Comment: Entendi, realmente me faltou interpretação de texto.

Comment: @riki481, na sua resposta vc comentou bem *"e graças a essa resposta, a pergunta ficou positiva novamente"*, mas isso não se refletiu na tradução... onde vc sugeriu por *"que depois recebeu uma pontuação"*, o mais próximo do *"that goes on to receive"* seria *"que passou a receber"* ou *"que passou a ter"*. Além disso, o *"Responder 5 ou mais questões"* é diferente do que tem no texto original *"Answer score of 5 or more to a question"*, que seria mais algo como *"(...) a uma pergunta"*, por causa do *"to a question"*, só pra ficar melhor ainda :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu entendi isso com o comentário do hkotusbo , mas obrigado por trazer uma nova perspectiva à correção.

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de mudar as sugestões, pois antes estavam "Responder 5 ou mais perguntas", sendo que na verdade basta responder **uma** pergunta que atenda aos critérios para ganhar a medalha. Inclusive, conforme o [FAQ do meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/401803), essa medalha pode ser ganha várias vezes, então se vc responder 5 perguntas que atenda aos critérios, ganhará 5 vezes a medalha (não apenas uma, como dava a entender a sugestão anterior)

Comment: acho que ficou bom. fiquei com dúvida nesse caso, devo aceitar a resposta ou aguardar que respondam quando for traduzida?

Comment: Eu acho que só faz sentido aceitar depois que for traduzida... Foi como eu fiz [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7877/112052), por exemplo